# Can I add multiple translate animation to one AnimationSet

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I want to add multiple translate animations to one AnimationSet. I am currently doing this by setting a listener to the AnimationSet and performing a new AnimationSet on the method onAnimationEnd() (see below).This is alot of code and was wondering if this can be done in one AnimationSet

Any idea?

```
view_2_anim_c.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            apa2.startAnimation(view_2_anim_d);
            //viewBAnimationD(apa2, 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AnimationSet can have any number of animations in it. If you would like the second translate animation to start after the first you can just set a startoffset on the second to be the same as the duration of the first. One limitation of this is that you can only perform the animations on a single view. If you wanted one view to translate and after that has finished a different view you should use the AnimationListener to run a new animation.

Comment: Thanks! What if I have a combination of animations to do in one move like a rotate, alpha and rotate? Would you also do this in one AnimationSet with startoffset?

Comment: Yup that would be the easiest way. You can have them run at the same time as well, all depends on the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Is there any limitation on how many moves I make in a single set?

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said but have a different problem. Please take a look..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327884/issue-running-multiple-animations-in-an-animationset